# Use tmux for managing multiple downloaders as a supervisorctl service?

Tags: linux, bash, tmux, wget

I have many data-servers I need to download data from via http as soon as it is available. For each server I start a `bash` "`while true`"-loop and within that a `wget` to poll the server for new data. To start all the `bash`s I created a `tmux` config starting a window for every loop such loop and `wget`. This adds the benefit of easier inspecting what is happening.

I want to create a `supervisor`-service from this config, which would allow me to start, stop, and restart this `tmux` and its downloading clients all at once.

However, when I quit `tmux`, by the very nature of `tmux`, the `bash`s and their `wget`s keep running. Is there a way around that, so I can quit everything and restart everything with a simple `supvervisorctl tmuxservice restart`?

Comment: Why not the simple kill-server?

Comment: I don't know of that? How can the command you mentioned be used to achive my mission?

Answer (score 1):

The [tmux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) has the following commands you might find useful:

> kill-server
>   Kill the tmux server and clients and destroy all sessions.
>
> kill-session [-t target-session]
>   Destroy the given session, closing any windows linked to it and no other sessions, and detaching all clients attached to it.
>
> list-clients [-t target-session]
>   (alias: lsc) List all clients attached to the server. If target-session is specified, list only clients connected to that session.
>
> list-commands
>   (alias: lscm) List the syntax of all commands supported by tmux.
>
> list-sessions
>   (alias: ls) List all sessions managed by the server.

You can use these commands within *tmux* as follows, for instance:

```
  tmux list-commands
```

You can now list your sessions,

```
   tmux list-clients
```

and you can now kill exactly the client you choose, by means of

```
  tmux kill-session -t 1
```

(if you want to kill the first session, for instance). In doing so, the sessions are not simply detached, they are killed. See this example:

```
 $ tmux list-session
   1: 1 windows (created Sun Jan 26 20:31:16 2014) [271x63] (attached)
   4: 1 windows (created Mon Jan 27 22:38:14 2014) [103x28] (attached)
 $ tmux  list-clients
   /dev/pts/6: 1 [271x64 xterm] (utf8) 
   /dev/pts/7: 4 [103x29 xterm] (utf8) 

 $ ps ax | grep ssh
   1160 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
   1811 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
  10733 pts/0    S+     0:00 ssh -Y me@sony
  11093 pts/13   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
 $ tmux kill-session -t 1
 $ ps ax | grep ssh
   1160 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
   1811 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
  12043 pts/13   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

As you can see, I had an active *ssh* connection to a pc called *sony*, in session 1 of tmux. When I killed it, the connection vanished.

I think this is how these commands will help you.